# SwiftUI | TextField в List

Tags: list, macos, swiftui

Есть вью - ячейка, в ней редактируется соответсвующий ей контент с помощью `TextField`. Таких ячеек более 2000, так как `ScrollView` безбожно лагает при таком объёме контента, я использую лист, но из-за этого пропадает возможность взаимодействия с полями.

Есть ли возможность вернуть работоспособность полям, без потери производительности?

```
struct CommandCellView: View 
{
    var body: some View
    {
        GeometryReader { g in
            HStack
            {
                TextField("0000", text: ...)
                    .frame(width: g.size.width/3)
                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View 
{
    var body: some View 
    {
        GeometryReader { g in
            List
            {
                ForEach(commands) { command in
                    CommandCellView(command.number)
                        .padding(.vertical, 1)
                }

                .frame(maxWidth: g.size.width / 3.7)
                .padding(.vertical, 2)
            }
         }             
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сработал такой вариант, читаю `minY` координату, и если она вне зоны видимости, ставлю вместо неё `EmptyView` с рамкой равной ячейке по высоте.
Производительность примерно такая же как при использовании `List`

```
ScrollView
{
    ForEach(commands) { command in
        GeometryReader { cell in
            if cell.frame(in: .global).minY > -20 && cell.frame(in: .global).minY < g.size.height + 20
            {
                CommandCellView(command.number)
                        .padding(.vertical, 1)
            } else {
                EmptyView()
                    .frame(height: 20)
            }
        }
    }
}
```